# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8956DA430 (user32.dll)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, program-entry-point, game-development

I get an error when trying to load my Window Application, the error is called "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8956DA430 (user32.dll) in Tennis.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location"

Windows.cpp -

```
Windows32::Windows32()
{
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)

{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {   Windows32* window = (Windows32*)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)window);
        window->onCreate();
        break;
       // case WM_CREATE;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {   
        Windows32* window = (Windows32*)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        window->onDestroy();
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    default:
        return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);

    }

    return NULL;
}



bool Windows32::init()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyWindows32Class";
    wc.lpszClassName = L"";
    wc.style = NULL;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;


    if (!::RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return false;

   // if (!window)
     //   window = this;


    m_hwnd=::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, L"MyWindows32Class", L"DirectX Application", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1024, 768,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, this);


  
    if (!m_hwnd)
        return false;

    ::ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    ::UpdateWindow(m_hwnd);

    //::RegisterClassEx(&wc);
 

  
    
    m_is_run = true;
    return true;
}

bool Windows32::broadcast()
{
    MSG msg;

    this->onUpdate();

    while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    Sleep(1);
    return true;
}


bool Windows32::release()
{
    if (!::DestroyWindow(m_hwnd))
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool Windows32::isRun()
{
    return m_is_run;
}

void Windows32::onCreate() {

}

void Windows32::onUpdate() {

}
void Windows32::onDestroy()
{
    m_is_run = false;
}

Windows32::~Windows32() {

}
```

Windows.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
class Windows32 
{
public:
    Windows32();
    bool init();
    bool broadcast();
    bool release();
    bool isRun();

    virtual void onCreate();
    virtual void onUpdate();
    virtual void onDestroy();




    ~Windows32();
protected:
    HWND m_hwnd;
    bool m_is_run;
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Windows32App.h"

int main() {
    Windows32App app;
    if (app.init())
    {
        while (app.isRun())
        {
            app.broadcast();
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

WindowsApp.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Windows32.h"


class Windows32App: public Windows32
{
public:
   Windows32App();
   ~Windows32App();



// Inherited via Windows32
virtual void onCreate() override;
virtual void onUpdate() override;
virtual void onDestroy() override;
```

};

Windows32App.cpp

```
#include "Windows32App.h"



Windows32App::Windows32App()
{
}

Windows32App::~Windows32App()
{
}

void Windows32App::onCreate()
{
Windows32::onCreate();
}

void Windows32App::onUpdate()
{
Windows32::onUpdate();
}

void Windows32App::onDestroy()
{
Windows32::onDestroy();
}
```

I have tried searching up on the internet and looking for answers and I have tried the debugger

Comment: WinAPI is hard. Converting it into encapsulated C++ is even harder... Do you have a special reason to try to roll your own instead of directly using MFC classes? For the same reason, while VS code is a good tool for writing portable code, for writing Windows dedicated applications or library, Visual Studio Community Edition is probably better fitted...

Comment: ... Additionaly, Microsoft VS comes with a wizard that will provide you with a minimal but working GUI application, with and working development configuration. Much easier to start from a working code and tweak it to meet your requirements than trying to rebuild everything from scratch. Too many possible mistake points IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement constructor which creates `Window32` from `HWND`. If you simply cast `HWND` to `Window32*`, then it could lead to segfault because you write to and read from memory that is outside the bounds of the area that `hwnd` points to. In other words, your cast will not automatically create `Window32` from `HWND`. Here is my suggestion:

```
public:
    Windows32(HWND hWnd)
    {
        this->m_hwnd = hWnd;
        this->m_is_run = true;
    }
```

Use

```
Windows32 window(((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->lpCreateParams);
```

instead

```
Windows32* window = (Windows32*)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->lpCreateParams;
```

Comment: Which class would I implement the constructor in?

Comment: In class Windows32.